# How can I take a certain amount of items from a chest using a hopper in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a Nether wart farm with Redstone++'s capability to dispense seeds, saplings, nether warts and actually plant them. The farm works and automatically harvests and plants the nether wart. All I need to do now is restock the dispensers when they are empty with 32 nether warts from the chest containing all the harvest. This is where I am stuck as I do not know how to achieve this - all I know is that it has something to do with comparators - a component which I do not fully understand.

I am using Minecraft 1.12.2 in Java Edition and Forge 14.23.5.2831 using the Roguelike Adventures and Dungeons modpack.

Below are images of my contraption (note that I am also using the Uppers mod for the upside down hoppers):

[image: Front view]
[image: Side view]

Comment: How many items do you want to take out of the chest? One?

Comment: @Reflexive Half a stack for each slice so 5 and a half stacks out of the chest

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Can't you just let a hopper/chest minecart drive quickly over a row of hoppers so that only a bit is put into each chest/hopper below? Also, I don't see any upside-down hoppers. What would they do?

Answer (score 2):

I found it always most reliable to count out *n* of *a thing* in Minecraft by using a timer that utilizes *that thing* for own timing. In this case we want to put *n* items using a hopper, so a timer based on transferring items using hoppers is the optimal solution.

[image]

The hopper near the comparator contains as many (arbitrary) items as we want inserted into the minecart. The other hopper of that pair is empty - this, alongside with the two torches, the comparator and a bit of redstone dust, comprises a signal extender that switches the torch on the input block (the one with a button on it; obviously attach whatever timing/activation source you want instead of the button) for duration of moving the items to the other hopper. Meanwhile, there's another hopper next to the same block that locks "return" of the items for the duration of the pulse extension - this one connected to storage and aimed into the minecart. The other torch is connected to a falling edge detector (comprised of 3 repeaters) - after finishing the cycle, the minecart is sent away to distribute the items.

[image]
[image]

Caveats:

- the signal extender has a "cooldown" of time equal to the duration of the pulse it generates. You must wait at least the same amount of time as it takes to insert the items into the cart, between uses of the system.
- the hopper aimed into the cart should contain one item, otherwise the first batch will be 1 short.
- the hopper loading the cart must be fed from a passive container, or from a hopper aimed in a bogus direction (sideways). It can't have items forcefully inserted by another hopper into it while it's locked.
- the system doesn't have any protections for running out of stock, or activation before the cooldown is elapsed.

Comment: Perhaps build one of those auto-reset clocks. They output a signal while the items are being transferred *there* and *back* before shutting off. Again there is a caveat, and that is that each item in the clock is worth 2 instead of 1..

Answer (score 0):

Hopper  minecarts can't easily be controlled, what you can do is change the speed of the minecart, the less time the hopper minecart has under the chest the less items it will take.